# How to clean image urls in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, url

I have a dataframe in which I have some image urls stored in a column.
I need to clean the image urls for further processing and currently the image urls are in this format-

```
df['image url'][1]
'https://www.example.com/newshop/images/backup/detailed/olivia.jpg#{[EN]:;}'

df['image url'][2]
'https://www.example.com/newshop/images/backup/detailed/Monkey_copy.jpg#{[EN]:Monkey;}'
```

What should be the best way to clean the image urls so that I have a correct image url in my datfarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with selecting first lists by indexing `str[0]`:

```
df['image url'] = df['image url'].str.split('#', 1).str[0]
```

Or use list comprehension if performance is important and no `NaN`s:

```
df['image url'] = [x.split('#', 1)[0] for x in df['image url']]
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'image url':['https://www.example.com/newshop/olivia.jpg#{[EN]:;}',
                                'https://www.example.com/newshop/Monkey_copy.jpg#{[EN]:Monkey;}']})
#[20000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

df['image url'] = [x.split('#', 1)[0] for x in  df['image url']]
df['image url1'] = df['image url'].str.split('#', 1).str[0]
print (df)

In [215]: %timeit df['image url'] = [x.split('#', 1)[0] for x in  df['image url']]
8.1 ms ± 1.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [216]: %timeit df['image url1'] = df['image url'].str.split('#', 1).str[0]
21.4 ms ± 638 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your examples, you can use [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to convert your strings to URLs. This assumes you don't have `#` in any part of your URL which matters.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'image url': ['https://www.example.com/newshop/images/backup/detailed/olivia.jpg#{[EN]:;}',
                                 'https://www.example.com/newshop/images/backup/detailed/Monkey_copy.jpg#{[EN]:Monkey;}']})

df['image url'] = df['image url'].str.split('#', 1).str[0]
# alternative:
# df['image url'] = df['image url'].str.split('#', 1, expand=True).iloc[:, 0]

print(df['image url'].iloc[0])

https://www.example.com/newshop/images/backup/detailed/olivia.jpg
```